# Simple example of the construction and application of a .d.ts file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm reading through this documentation trying to understand the purpose of TypeScript `.d.ts` files or declaration files:

> When using an external JavaScript library, or new host API, you’ll need to use a declaration file (.d.ts) to describe the shape of that library.

Can someone please provide a simple example of what that means and how to apply it?  The document does it, but it just seems like there's a simpler way to explain it.  For example if I wanted to use moment.js with TypeScript then I would need the following `momentjs.d.ts` file...

But Why do I need the file?  In other words why can't I just import and use `momentjs` without the `*.d.ts` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For moment specifically, you will just have to run `typings install --global dt~moment` ("install the global declaration file of moment from the source Definitely Typed").

The reason you need a declaration file, is because the external library is probably not written in typescript. As a result, you have to define what the api of the library looks like, so typescript knows roughly what is available.

The easiest declaration file would look something like this:

**custom-typings/moment.d.ts**

```
declare module 'moment'
```

This will allow you to use the moment library wherever you want, but you won't have any of the juicy autocomplete or typechecking available for any of the functions of this library. However, typechecking for an external module is extremely helpful, as you probably aren't very familiar with the api, compared to the code you wrote yourself.

Comment: Thanks - that helped a little bit - what I'm really looking for is a simple example of what the file does for me.  In other words a simple scenario with a few lines of code attempting to use something simple like momentjs and if I don't have the .d.ts file, then this happens, ... and if I create a .d.ts file with these lines in it, then the thing no longer happens...

Comment: I updated my answer a bit, to answer your update. Does this help you out?